# convert graph into formula

Tags: charts

Is there some kind of a way to transfer a line chart from paper to formulas or any kind of precise reading? I have a chart where I have x and y axis values and I need to find the value in graph:

[image: chart]

For best solution I would like to get these values using some kind of formulas, because I find x and y values using excel spreadsheet.

Comment: You are likely looking for *curve fitting* software.